# Spinner arrow button is showing in white

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using spinner in my registration form.

Following are my problems in implementing spinner.

1. arrow triangle in spinner on right side is showing in white color but it should show in black color.
2. Underline is not showing in spinner like it is showing in edittext.

**Following is my code**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="#C9CACC"  
>

 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/employerType"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:entries="@array/employerTypeArr"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"                   
        />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: And..we are all Fortune Fortellers and can see your code from here, right? Atleast provide us with some code,.. XML from Spinner, code where do you use the Spinner..etc.

Comment: I have updated my question and add source code of spinner

Comment: Can you test it, if you remove the `android:background=""` if it's still dispalys it that way?

Comment: In that case arrow does not show at all.

Comment: I am thinking it might have to do something with the parent `ScrollView`settings with the background, that it might be the same colour as the Spinners Arrow / Line. Hm.